# What does “not as [adjective] as him” imply?

Tags: meaning, comparisons

If it is written that X is not as tall as Y, it indicates that X and Y have unequal heights. But does this necessarily imply that X is shorter than Y?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Not worth the paper it's printed on" - wrong meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15890/not-worth-the-paper-its-printed-on-wrong-meaning)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the absence of further elaboration, **yes**:  "I am not as X as you" implies that you have more X-quality than I do.  If X is "tall", then I am shorter than you.

It is possible to follow up for a humorous (or insulting) reversal of the normal implication:

> I am not as good as he is... I'm actually way better.

But if you don't do this explicit countering, the default reading is that "not as X as" is always "less X than".

Comment: That shows that it's an invited inference, or possibly a Gricean implicature. To the extent they're different. What's interesting is that this only works with the _at least as ... as_ [variety of equative](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/118055/15299); the _exactly as ... as_ doesn't have this property, at least not in the same way: _I'm not exactly as good as he is_ gives the impression that the speaker is changing the basis for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Logically, I do not think it should imply X is shorter than Y.

The definition of "as" according to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/as) is

> to the same degree, amount, or extent; similarly; equally

So, if I were to say "X is as tall as Y." I would be saying that X is equally as tall as Y.

If I were to negate that statement, then I would have "X is not as tall as Y." Which would be saying that X is not equally as tall as Y.

However, in general speech, I do agree with Hellion that it implies X is shorter than Y.

Answer (score -2):

I see from the comments and  downvotes that I have to spell it out completely for some readers.

First, if X is not as tall as Y, we can say that one of them is taller; that X is not equal to Y. Let us first assume for the sake of argument that Y is the taller, meaning that X < Y. My original comment read:

X < Y has the inescapable corollary that Y > X. As posed, the question needs no further answer.

I had assumed (it seems wrongly) that readers would appreciate that there is an equally logical mirror statement:

X > Y has the inescapable corollary that Y > X.

Comment: You seem to have confused ≠ with <.

Comment: @SomethingDark *not as* is more closely correlated with `<` than `≠` btw. Leaving out the word *as* would change it to `≠`.

Comment: @insidesin - For the most part that's true, but then you have examples like in Hellion's answer.

Comment: @SomethingDark What do you mean? Then that would be `>` and still not `≠` :/

Comment: The issue here is the implicit double-meaning of "as X as Y"; height is viewed as an ascending property, so "as tall as" implicitly means "*at least* as tall as" - but it can also be interpreted as "exactly the same height as", leading to the sort of thing @Hellion pointed out - the humour comes from subverting the expectations set up by the double meaning.